How to use distance between stretched objects in turtle python
I'm working on making a pong game as an exercise, and i'm trying to handle the ball direction after it hits the paddle, I want the ball to go straight if it hits the center of the paddle and to go up with an angle 135 if it hits the upper segment and to go down with an angle 225 if it hits the lower segment.
I couldn't find any function that can help me to solve this issue in the turtle library,
I need a functionality that can help me to determine where did the ball hits the paddle.
appreciate the help.
I tried to use the distance function but the problem that it gives me the same distance if the ball reaches the upper segment or the lower one.
import time
import turtle

turtle.setup(startx=2200, width=900)
turtle.tracer(0)


class Ball(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('circle')
        self.penup()

    # def move(self):
    #     """Moves the ball."""
    #     self.forward(20)
    #     # if self.xcor() > 560:
    #     #     self.bounce(angle=180)
    #     # elif self.xcor() < -560:
    #     #     self.bounce(angle=0)
    #
    # def bounce(self, angle):
    #     """Bounce the ball when it hits the paddles or the ceiling."""
    #     self.setheading(angle)
    #     self.forward(20)
    #
    # def collision(self):
    #     pass
    #
    # def up(self):
    #     self.sety(self.ycor() + 1)
    #
    # def down(self):
    #     self.sety(self.ycor() - 1)
    #
    # def go_right(self):
    #     self.setx(self.xcor() + 1)
    #
    # def go_left(self):
    #     self.setx(self.xcor() - 1)


class PaddlePart(turtle.Turtle):
    """Represents the paddle part"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('square')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=6, stretch_len=1)
        self.penup()


paddle_part1 = PaddlePart()
paddle_part1.setx(20)
print(paddle_part1.ycor())

ball = Ball()

# turtle.listen()
# turtle.onkeypress(fun=ball.up, key='Up')
# turtle.onkeypress(fun=ball.down, key='Down')
# turtle.onkeypress(fun=ball.go_right, key='Right')
# turtle.onkeypress(fun=ball.go_left, key='Left')

while True:
    print(ball.distance(paddle_part1))
    turtle.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)

# turtle.mainloop()



I've solved the problem by making the paddle of 3 separate segments, and each segement is a turtle class with the square shape.
so then based on which segement the ball hits it redirected.
final version of the game

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
